# Getting compilation error with method: "not all code paths return a value"

Tags: c#, asp.net, methods, compiler-errors, boolean

I can't figure this out why I keep getting the compilation error: "not all code paths return a value".  I am writing a simple class method that is supposed to return true if the account is available to use and false if the account is not available or is null/empty.  The code for the method is below:

```
public static bool AccountAvailable(int AccountId)
{
    try
    {            
        bool accountavailable;

        string queryTransaction = "Select Count(AccountID) FROM Accounts WHERE AccountID = " + AccountId.ToString() + " AND AccountUsed = 0";

        //grab a connection to the database
        Database database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();

        //create an instance of the command
        DbCommand command = database.GetSqlStringCommand(queryTransaction);

        object dataobject = command.ExecuteScalar();

        if (dataobject == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(dataobject)))
        {
            accountavailable = false;
        }

        else if (Convert.ToInt32(dataobject) == 0)
        {
            accountavailable = false;
        }

        else if (Convert.ToInt32(dataobject) > 0)
        {
            accountavailable = true;
        }

        else
        {
            accountavailable = true;
        }

        return accountavailable;
    }

    catch
    {

    }
}
```

Any help or advice on this would be appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Explain what you believe happens when an exception is thrown from within that `try` block. Also explain *why you have a try block in the first place*. Building a try-catch as you have done here is a "worst practice", so if you explain why you've done so, we can disabuse you of whatever mistaken ideas you have that have led you to write this bad code.

Comment: You should not be catching all exceptions and then doing nothing with them.  If you have a problem you'll never find out what went wrong.  If you encountered a problem that you weren't able to deal with in your code then you need to know about it, meaning at the *very* least, you should be logging the problem, and more likely than not you should be letting the exception bubble up because you can't meaningfully so what is asked of you if you hit an unexpected exception.

Comment: Oh, and you shouldn't be generating your queries by concatting strings, it leaves you open to SQL injection.

Comment: @Servy: Excellent advice, but to be pedantic, in this case it would be hard to inject anything useful with an int.

Comment: @spender True, I noticed that after I commented, but figured it's still worth leaving.

Comment: All excellent suggestions. Eric - try/catch was done just in case there was an issue during processing of this info (did not want an ugly user error on production).  @Servy - I have a version with SQL parameters but I swapped out the code with concat strings as it helps me troubleshoot before I go to production with this.  I put "return accountavailable" after the catch block, adding a "return false" to the catch block, but that still does not help as now something is breaking within the try block that causes the method to hit the catch block everytime.

Comment: @thenextmogul Then you'll need to debug your program to see what that is (since you aren't logging the information to show it to you without debugging).  There isn't enough information for us to know what the problem is.  It could be anything from connections issues, your query not being valid, the results not being properly parsed, or any number of other options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an exception is thrown in your code before you return a value then control moves to the `catch` block.  It then reaches the end of the method without returning anything.

Either return something within, or after, the catch block.

Answer (score 1):

In your catch block, add a return:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // your code
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The suggest to try this code

```
public static bool AccountAvailable(int AccountId)
{
    bool accountavailable = false;
    try
    {            

        string queryTransaction = "Select Count(AccountID) FROM Accounts WHERE AccountID = " + AccountId.ToString() + " AND AccountUsed = 0";

        //grab a connection to the database
        Database database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();

        //create an instance of the command
        DbCommand command = database.GetSqlStringCommand(queryTransaction);

        object dataobject = command.ExecuteScalar();

        if (dataobject == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(dataobject)))
        {
            accountavailable = false;
        }

        else if (Convert.ToInt32(dataobject) == 0)
        {
            accountavailable = false;
        }

        else if (Convert.ToInt32(dataobject) > 0)
        {
            accountavailable = true;
        }

        else
        {
            accountavailable = true;
        }

    }

    catch
    {

    }
    return accountavailable;
}
```

Comment: I correct the compilation error and respond to question. I don't judge of the quality of coding

Comment: Actually, on a second look, this won't even compile.  `accountavailable` is not definitely assigned when you use it at the end, which is a compiler error.

Comment: I understand, i'm french and my english is not perfect i replace "correct" by "suggest" in my post